# Sum of two calculated columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm calculating two rows like this :

```
CASE 
    WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1)) = 1
        THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1) 
    else 0 
end AS RoomNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number))) = 1
        THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number)) 
    else 0 
end AS HallNumber,
```

I need to make another column that calculates the sum of RoomNumber and HallNumber, I tried this :

```
SELECT *, (RoomNumber + HallNumber) AS Sum
FROM Table
```

But I got invalid column name error.
How can I get the sum of these two columns? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really only have two options since you can't reuse an alias at the same level in which it was defined.  Either you can just add together the two `CASE` statements:

```
CASE WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1)) = 1
     THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1) 
     ELSE 0 END AS RoomNumber,
CASE WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number))) = 1
     THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number)) 
     ELSE 0 END AS HallNumber,
(CASE WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1)) = 1
     THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1) 
     ELSE 0 END
+
CASE WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number))) = 1
     THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number)) 
     ELSE 0 END) AS Sum
```

Or you can try wrapping your current query as a subquery, where the aliases you already defined would be available:

```
SELECT t.RoomNumber,
       t.HallNumber,
       (t.RoomNumber + t.HallNumber) AS Sum
FROM
(
    ... your original query ...
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

You need subquery to sum up computed columns.

```
SELECT a.*, (a.RoomNumber + a.HallNumber) AS Sum
   (SELCT  CASE 
        WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1)) = 1
            THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.RNumber,1,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) - 1) 
        else 0 
    end AS RoomNumber,
    CASE 
        WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number))) = 1
            THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Table.R.Number,CHARINDEX('+',dbo.Table.RNumber) + 1,LEN(dbo.Table.R.Number)) 
        else 0 
    end AS HallNumber) AS a
```